# Validation on Keypress using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

This code is under in the Keypress Event

There's no problem when I try to input -1, -2 or 1.1 -1.3 but when I try to input like 1/2 and 1/4 in textbox I only stock on this " 1/ ".
I think there is something wrong in my code but there's no error message at all and I can't figure it out. . 
Any kind of help and suggestion is really appreciated. .

```
    Dim tb As TextBox = CType(sender, TextBox)  
    Dim chr As Char = e.KeyChar  

    If IsNumeric(e.KeyChar) And Not e.KeyChar = "-" Then  
        e.Handled = Not IsNumeric(tb.Text & e.KeyChar)  
    ElseIf IsNumeric(e.KeyChar) And Not e.KeyChar = "/" Then  
        e.Handled = Not IsNumeric(tb.Text & e.KeyChar)  
    ElseIf e.KeyChar = "." Then  
        If Not (tb.SelectedText = "." Or IsNumeric(tb.Text & e.KeyChar)) Then  
            e.Handled = True  
        End If  
    ElseIf e.KeyChar = "/" Then  
        If tb.SelectionStart <> 1 Or Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(tb.Text, 1) = "/" Then  
            e.Handled = True  
        End If  
    ElseIf e.KeyChar = "-" Then  
        If tb.SelectionStart <> 0 Or Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(tb.Text, 1) = "-" Then  
            e.Handled = True  
        End If  
    ElseIf Not Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) Then  
        e.Handled = True  
    End If
```

Comment: What does "only stock on this " 1/ " mean?

Comment: @rontornambe I think the OP means, "He's only stuck on 1/", just my guess...

Comment: i want to input like this: "1/2" but when i do it's stock on this "1/" i can't add any numbers anymore.

Comment: "1/2" is NOT numeric.  The word is "stuck", btw.  Using a debugger to step through this type of code is highly recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue with first condition itself, where you check isnumeric which return false due to "/" symbol.

```
  Dim tb As TextBox = CType(sender, TextBox)
        Dim chr As Char = e.KeyChar

        If IsNumeric(e.KeyChar) And Not e.KeyChar = "-" Then
            If tb.Text.Contains("/") = False Then
                e.Handled = Not IsNumeric(tb.Text & e.KeyChar)
            End If

        ElseIf IsNumeric(e.KeyChar) And Not e.KeyChar = "/" Then
            e.Handled = Not IsNumeric(tb.Text & e.KeyChar)
        ElseIf e.KeyChar = "." Then
            If Not (tb.SelectedText = "." Or IsNumeric(tb.Text & e.KeyChar)) Then
                e.Handled = True
            End If
        ElseIf e.KeyChar = "/" Then
            If tb.SelectionStart <> 1 Or Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(tb.Text, 1) = "/" Then
                e.Handled = True
            End If
        ElseIf e.KeyChar = "-" Then
            If tb.SelectionStart <> 0 Or Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(tb.Text, 1) = "-" Then
                e.Handled = True
            End If
        ElseIf Not Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If
```

Comment: Or you can comment that statement too.

Comment: i try your code and yet. . get this error: Conversion from string "1/2" to type 'Double' is not valid.

Comment: i get the error on this part of my codes                                         If txta1.Text = 1 Then
            numa1 = "x"
        ElseIf txta1.Text = -1 Then
            numa1 = "-x"
        Else
            numa1 = txta1.Text + "x"
        End If

Answer (score 0):

I think you can avoid this error and a lot of complexity by testing whether the the entire value is numeric or not instead of testing each character. For example:

```
If IsNumeric(tb.Text) Then
   e.Handled = true
End If
```

Is there some reason you cannot do this?

Comment: This won't work.  The OP is trying to put numbers *into* the TextBox.

Comment: So what? IsNumeric handles numbers, decimal points, fractions, etc. What I am missing here?

Comment: Your code says, if the TextBox has a number in it, stop all keyboard action.  So as soon as you enter a "1", you can't add another digit to the TextBox.  Also, IsNumeric can't handle fractions, so IsNumeric("1/2") returns false.

Comment: You're right. Way too late at night to be answering these kinds of questions.